# No output durning debug with NetBeans and XDebug

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, xdebug

I've run into some strange problem, after upgradeing my PHP to 5.4 I have a problem with debugging in NetBeans 7.0.1. When debbuging session is active the browser does not show any output but the debugger runs normally. I can set breakpoints in my application, and they work normaly, but server does not return anything back to the browser. After sending end of session request output works normally.

Here are my settings in php.ini

```
zend_extension = c:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0RC1-5.4-vc9.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="c:\php\xdebug.log"
```

According to xdebug log, xdebug is conntected to IDE, and IDE does not complain on anything.

Any clues would be much appriciated.
Here is my php.ini file: http://pastebin.com/z8LBsmmw

Comment: Is `html_errors` enabled in your php.ini?

Comment: Check for xdebug updates. Do bugreports if you can reproduce your issue.

Comment: hmmmm I think I read somewhere that Xdebug won't run on PHP 5.4 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have enabled `output_buffering` ? also, enabling an output_handler(like a compression handler, eg gzip) can buffer, at least up until a certain chunk size is reached.

browsers buffer too sometimes. outputting a bunch of whitespace can get around that.

Comment: Changing output buffering to off didnt change anything. Here is my whole php.ini: http://pastebin.com/z8LBsmmw

Comment: you had a value of 4096, meaning it will buffer and flush only after an increment of 4096 bytes has accumulated. Make sure you are editing the correct php.ini(check via phpinfo()), and make sure the config changes take effect(just reboot).

Comment: Did that, nothing change. If that would be an issue, would it also not affect non xdebug sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem; someone may find my solution useful.

Besides turning off `output_buffering` and any output handlers, as @goat already mentioned, you have to turn on `implicit_flush`.

As the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) states:

> Changing this to **TRUE** tells PHP to tell the output layer to flush itself automatically after every output block. This is equivalent to calling the PHP function [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) after each and every call to print or echo and each and every *HTML* block.
>
> When using PHP within an web environment, turning this option on has serious performance implications and is generally recommended for debugging purposes only.